# CodePipeline fails every time in CodeDeploy stage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

CodePipeline fails every time in CodeDeploy stage.
Every time I push code to CodeCommit CodePipeline successefully fetching it but it's always fails in CodeDeploy stage.

Here is error message:
`The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems.`

appspec.yml:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
- source: /
 destination: /home/ec2-user/app

permissions:
- object: /
   pattern: "**"
   owner: ec2-user
   group: ec2-user

hooks:
ApplicationStop:
   - location: scripts/app-stop
     timeout: 10
     runas: ec2-user

AfterInstall:
   - location: scripts/install-npm
     timeout: 1200
     runas: ec2-user

ApplicationStart:
   - location: scripts/app-start
     timeout: 60
     runas: ec2-user
```

scripts:
app-start:

```
#!/bin/bash
forever start /app/index.js
```

app-stop:

```
#!/bin/bash
forever stopall
```

install-npm:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd app && npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

For code deploy, you've to make sure that your instance has the codedeploy agent installed on it, else it will give you an error like "

> The overall deployment failed because of too many individual instances
>   failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for
>   deployment or some instances in your deployment group are
>   experiencing problems"

you can follow this URL to install codedeploy agent on your EC2 instance.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-install.html